# Navigating/Navigated events aren't working in PhantomJS WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I've subscribed to the Navigated and Navigating events of the WebDriver but the events are not triggered. What's their use if they do not work? Is there something additional that I need to do in order for them to get triggered?

```
_driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(_driver);
eventDriver.Navigating += navigatedHandler;
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(yt);

private void navigatedHandler(object sender, WebDriverNavigationEventArgs args)
{
    MessageBox.Show("navigating");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've circumvented the event mechanism by navigating using your initial `IWebDriver` object. Calling the methods on the `EventFiringWebDriver` instance will properly fire the events. In the case of your example code:

```
_driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(_driver);
eventDriver.Navigating += navigatingHandler;

// This line changes. Use eventDriver instead of _driver to navigate. 
eventDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(yt);
```